# Orbit css selectors

Tags: css, selector, orbit

I'm using Foundation Orbit slider. It's working fine except that I need to do have some css (move the caption) applied to a specific slider on the page.

If I use following selector it does the change, only problem it's a global change.

```
.orbit-wrapper .orbit-caption
{
    bottom:-30px;
}
```

I have tried different selectors with the id of the container div but it never gets applied.

```
#promotion .orbit-caption
{
    bottom:-30px;
}
```

If I check the css values in the browser, the correct values are there, but they are not applied to the element somehow. Only when I change the selector as in the first example above I get the change.

I'm not an expert in css, but the selectors I have tried with do work in normal circumstances.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: !important is your friend here. Atleast for trouble shooting purpose.

Comment: Tried !important, didn't help. If I look in browsers tools, I can see it's reading my value and it's overriding the default from .orbit-wrapper .orbit-caption selector, but it's not applying to the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out whats going on. Orbit copies the caption element to an element outside of the original orbit container (my div). I didn't notice this from the beginning because it left the original captions where I created them, so I was debugging them.

The solution is to create another wrapper element and use that as an selector for the captions. The following is working if I create a div with id=promotion-wrapper containing the orbit slider div.

```
#promotion-wrapper .orbit-caption
{
    bottom:-30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure the element has **position: relative;**?

```
.orbit-wrapper .orbit-caption
{
    position: relative;
    bottom:-30px;
}
```

Without that or position: absolute; the "bottom" property won't do anything.

Comment: It has position:absolute. I'm trying to override the bottom value. If I use the global selector in your code above it's working, but if I try to override with id selector the browser sees the value and reports it to override the global seletor but the change is not applied to the element.

Comment: The thing is that Orbit does add elements and styles via javascript so the final html is not whats in my code and thats why my selectors doesn't work i believe. Hoping someone would know what Orbit does to the html elements and that would help knowing what selectors to use.

Answer (score 0):

I found a new and easy solution  ,

Just add **margin-top** and change **position to relative**

```
.orbit-container .orbit-slides-container > * .orbit-caption {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top:40px;
    background-color:#F3F3F3;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    font-size: 0.875em; }
```